# C++ use lambda function as template function specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda

Is it possible to use a lambda function to create an alias to a template class function? Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int calcDouble(int a) { return a * 2; }
int calcMultiply_10(int a) { return a * 10; }

struct foo
{
    template<void (*func)(int)>
    int generic(int value)
    {
        return func(value);
    }

    static auto double_10 = [this] { generic<calcDouble>(10); };
    static auto double_20 = [this] { generic<calcDouble>(20); };
    static auto multiply_10_20 = [this] { generic<calcMultiply_10>(20); };
}


int main() {
    foo f;

    cout << "double_10: " <<f.double_10() << endl;
    cout << "double_20: " <<f.double_20() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no "this" defined for static members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your particular example doesn't compile, and would be dangerous if it did - capturing `this` by value means that as soon as the class is copied/moved the captured `this` will point to a wrong or invalid memory location.

Just use member functions:

```
auto double_10()      { return generic<calcDouble>(10); }
auto double_20()      { return generic<calcDouble>(20); }
auto multiply_10_20() { return generic<calcMultiply_10>(20); }
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/d6cNmj6Uxbk68CjU)